# Primefaces calendar position

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to change position of calendar component by using CSS margin property.

```
<p style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 100px">
    <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date1}" mode="inline" id="inlineCal"/>
</p>
```

margin-top is working, 
but margin-left not.

How can I move calendar component in horizontal direction?

Comment: I dont know why, but margin-right is working, so i can use this trick:
style="margin-right: 10px; float: right;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How can I move calendar component in horizontal direction?
```

Use CSS's `float` propery . i.e : `float : left ;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

[> 'padding-left'](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_padding-left)

instead of margin-left...

Try this

```
<p style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 100px !important">
```

It may help you

Comment: Please check any css is overriding ur new css.. Place **!important** in front of that css.. It will work

Comment: no changes :(
I am using this style="margin-right: 10px; float: right; to move component relatively right border. It works for me.